# jQuery/CSS animate div width from left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to use jQuery to animate a div with a background picture decreasing in width from left to right whilst being absolutely positioned.

I need to make this compatible with IE8 hence using jQuery.

Here is a basic JSFiddle demo link with what I have so far, but it animates from right to left:

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/melon/V4XCb/5/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(document).on('click', '.splat', function(e){
        $(this).animate({width:"0px"},800);
    });
});

.splat {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}

<div class="splat"><!-- --></div>
```

I need it going in a different direction, like the following image:

[image: example of what I want to achieve]

Hoping someone could point me in the right direction (no pun intended!). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just change from 'left' to 'right'. Isn't it so simple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a wrapper and position the child div with `right:0`.

[**See this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/V4XCb/9/)

Comment: I've updated your demo http://jsfiddle.net/melon/V4XCb/12/ with my background image, text and aligned the elements right which now seems to work perfectly :) Thanks.

Comment: The `wrapper` is needed in order to position the child element relatively to the parent and not to the document. In practical use, you'll notice that the wrapper is essential unless the absolute position to the right of the document is your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

If i can understand your question, solution is replace left with right :)

http://jsfiddle.net/V4XCb/6/

```
.splat {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I've also updated your demo http://jsfiddle.net/melon/V4XCb/13/ and aligned the background image right which now works perfectly, this example doesn't require a wrapper so I'll go with this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can like this:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="splat"></div>
</div>

.box{
   width:200px;
   height: 200px;
}
.splat {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you could wrap your elem with a wrapper which is relative positioned element and do the following:

```
.splatWrapper {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: green;
    position: relative; //<-----needed
    top: 100px;  //<------------needed
    left: 100px; //<------------needed
 }
 .splat{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;     //<----------needed
    right: 0;   //<----------needed
 }
```

[**Try this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/V4XCb/11/)

Answer (score 0):

### You can use Scale Effect in Jquery :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(document).on('click', '.splat1', function(e){
        $(this).hide("scale");
    });    
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/V4XCb/14/